# Passing array Using Jquery Ajax to asp.net C# Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

What's up?

So i have a Array in UI Side and want to send it to controller's Action.
This is my Array :

```
var data = [
            {
                "receipt": {
                    "Service": "Saab",
                    "Order": "20"
                }
            },
            {
                "receipt": {
                    "Service": "Volvo",
                    "Order": "12"
                }
            },
            {
                "receipt": {
                    "Service": "BMW",
                    "Order": "25"
                }
            }
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        ]
```

Array length can be 100 or just 1 so it is important to manage all available details in data variable.

I want to send this array to controller with ajax and catch them in server side which can use and manage data . I have read all of similar questions but didn't help ...

Please help me, this problem is messing with me for over 3 weeks.

I used a simple statement of JQuery Ajax like this :

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "Json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: data,
            url: "api/Receipt",
            success: function (result) {
                // To Do
                console.info(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.info(result);
            }
        });
```

And in server side i tried this :

```
          [WebMethod]
    public IEnumerable<R> Receipt_Turn([FromBody] Object r)
    { }
```

I have data here but cant use them

Thank you so much;)

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: This sounds like someone asking for the answer to their school assignment without trying or supplying any examples of work they've tried themselves. This is not what Stack Overflow is for...

Comment: No this is for get order from a marketplace between 2 or more services.  Like you have bakery with 5 type bread.  I want 10 unit of every type you have . I dont want to calculate price in JS file cause its not safe , so i tride to use an api to get receipt details and return calculated price with a string of receipt. Please help me if you know the way , cause after 3 weeks trying and searching,  i realized that i cant handle this part alone... @haag1

Comment: I updated my question with information that you asked @sagi

Answer (score 0):

Its totally depend on how your api receive you data.

may be :-

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

or

```
{ string_name : JSON.stringify(data); }
```

both goes on body. Note : here string_name is for examples it is declare in api side..

Comment: Please give me the code that you think is better for my situation.   Ajax statement and api Gate  . Send it the way you think better and catch them the way you think is standard,  i will follow... @Toxy

Comment: I updated my question , please take a look @Toxy

Comment: share me whole api class. your updated question does not helping a bit, 
as for your first comment  the standard method is 

`$.ajax({type: "POST", .....data: JSON.stringify(data);, url: "api/Receipt",....});`

but you have to set the api accordingly to receive

Comment: Hi again . I created a new question with full information about my problem.  Please take a look.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67011223/15557820)   . @Toxy