# Converting a dynamic Variable to List<model> or array

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, type-conversion

I want to send this Array with Ajax to api :

```
var receipt = Array();

        receipt = [
            { 'Service': 'Saab', 'Order': '20' },
            { 'Service': 'Volvo', 'Order': '12' },
            { 'Service': 'BMW', 'Order': '25' }
        ];
```

And this is my Ajax body :

```
var r = JSON.stringify(receipt);
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "Json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: r,
            url: "api/Receipt",
            success: function (result) {
                // To Do
                console.info(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.info(result);
            }
        });
```

And this is what i get as Json :

```
        {[
            {
               "Service": "Saab",
               "Order": "20"
            },
            {
               "Service": "Volvo",
               "Order": "12"
             },
             {
               "Service": "BMW",
               "Order": "25"
              }
          ]}
```

And i catch them in api side Like this :

```
[Route("api/Receipt")]
    [WebMethod]
    public string Receipt_Turn(object obj)
    {
        dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj.ToString());

        if (dyn != null)
        {
            return dyn[1].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "false";
        }

    }
```

And it works,  the part `return dyn[1].ToString()` returns second record of my Array. But i want to convert this dynamic variable to a list or array of a model .

Here is my model :

```
[Serializable()]
    public class Receipt
    {
        public string Service { get; set; }
        public string Order { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to act with it like this :

```
string serv = receipt[1].Service;
```

How can i do it ?

Thanks...

Comment: Can you share the json you are posting via Ajax?

Comment: Sure.  Thanks for responding back  . I updated my question. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Well this is my problem too . i will follow this Question to find my Answer . Cheers @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the Array Part in Your JS Script and Write it Like this :

```
var receipt = [
            { 'Service': 'Saab', 'Order': '20' },
            { 'Service': 'Volvo', 'Order': '12' },
            { 'Service': 'BMW', 'Order': '25' }
        ];
```

in this shape you are sending an Object. in your code i guess you are sending an `JArray` So it Will make some Problems in Converting from `JArray` to another Type .

in your API Side , Edit Your Code As Below :

```
public string Receipt_Turn(object r)
    {

        //important Line Here
        List<Receipt> rr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Receipt>>(r.ToString());

        if (rr != null)
        {
            return rr[1].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "false";
        }

    }
```

as you can see, we get it Like an Object and then we will be able to Get Ready your `DeserializeObject` part Like i mentioned.

you most declare a List of your Model, and after part `DeserializeObject` add that Type You want to Convert it to.

here Cause we Declared `List<Receipt>` , we should convert our `DeserializeObject` to it, so we add `<List<Receipt>>` after `DeserializeObject`.

and Finally you can use it Like You wish .

```
string serv = rr[1].Service;
```

Comment: OMG, You didn't just solved my problem . You  saved my life to  . Thank you 10000 times . Your answer was Great and complete ,theres no question left for me .... @ImanS3

Comment: Your Welcome . @SelenaMG

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using .NET Core, it should be able to bind it automatically if you do something like this:

````
```
[Route("api/Receipt")]
[WebMethod]
public string Receipt_Turn(List<Receipt> receipts)
{

    if (receipts != null)
    {
        return "seomthing";
    }
    else
    {
        return "false";
    }
}
```
````

Comment: No I'm Using asp.net web form's and i tried this . The value is null . I tried `Receipt receipt` . In this state `receipt` is like a array , even the count of records will appear.  But in each record,  the `Service` and `Order` is `null` .@dmalcaba